# What's the difference between a+i and a[i]

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I try to use a two dimensional character array to store strings,and then I want to use the function `strcmp` to compare two adjacent strings.

Here is the code,it is a successful one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[20][20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        scanf("%s",a[i]);//input
    for(int i=1;i<20;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(a[i],a[i-1])>0)//compare
        {
            //do something here
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to use `a+i` to subsitute `a[i]`,the problem occurs.(I'm a beginner of pointer and in my mind these two expressions are the same)

The second code is the following one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[20][20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        scanf("%s",a+i);//input
    for(int i=1;i<20;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(a+i,a+i-1)>0)//compare
        {
            //do something here
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Compiler tells me that there is an error in the line `if(strcmp(a+i,a+i-1)>0)//compare`with the following message.

`[Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[20]' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'`

I'm quite confused of this problem. However, if I just use `a+i` for the input part, it works well.So i want to konw the difference between `a+i` and `a[i]` and why `a+i` can't serve as the argument for `strcmp` but it can work in `scanf`.

Thanks.

Comment: correct a+i to *(a + i)

Comment: Aside: "cannot convert 'char (*)[30]'" and `char a[20][20];` look like one has a false magic number.  I'd expect both to have 20.

Comment: "if I just use a+i for the input part, it works well" is due to _undefined behavior_.  Right value, wrong type.

Comment: Thank you guys,it's really helpful.In this case a+i is interpreted as a pointer to another two dimensional character array,so it can't be used as an argument for strcmp.Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `a[i]` resolves to `*(a+i)`. Mind the star "*".

Long answer: at semantic level, `a[i]` is meant to access to element **i** of array **a**. This is internally done by finding out the address of **a**'s beginning in memory, then adding **i** times the size of an element to it to find the place of targeted element.

Aside from this, invoking **a** (an array name) alone is resolved into this array's address, thus into a pointer-typed expression. Moreover, "pointer arithmetics" states, when combining both integer and pointer values, the increment is the size of pointed element. Therefore, if you're pointing for instance a 32-bits integer at `a=0x80000000`, `a+1` will be `0x80000004`.

Comment: ... fun fact: `a[i]` is the same as `i[a]`. Reason: `+` being commutative: `*(a+i)` is  the same as `*(i+a)` which therefore is the same as `i[a]`